# Allow us to choose a doctype for Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Sometimes a specific doctype is required to reproduce an issue. Currently it's not possible to specify a doctype for a Stack Snippet's html section. I've tried this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>First button has less height than the other two:</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp; </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Test</a>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That snippet actually *needs* the doctype for the issue to be reproducible. However, it renders as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- etc -->
```

I don't think there's any other way (yet) to do this (no input somewhere, which is the way jsfiddle does it, see the difference between [html4](http://jsfiddle.net/ovhd360c/1/) and [html5](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtd1b9a/1/)), which is why I'm placing this feature request.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, though? What's the point? (honest question, asking what's the use case)

Comment: I was about to ask why the first button in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtd1b9a/) vs [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtd1b9a/1/) has a different height, and how to solve that. Without the specific differing doctypes the issue is not noticable. In other words, sometimes a situation is only visible with a specific doctype, and you may be stuck with that doctype, so in order to provide a repro as context for your question you need to be able to specify that doctype.

Comment: Moderately exotic feature request though, sure enough. I didn't mean to file my feature-request as high-prio of course, but it's still probably good for the back log.

Comment: Well, it somehow became the #2 popular [feature request for snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets+feature-request).

Comment: The REP! Waarrghhh-om-nom-NOM! Oh wait I get no rep here. Pffrt why do I even post on meta....? ;-)

Comment: I want to be able to choose a MIME type for stacksnippets...

Comment: @MrLister Interesting. Perhaps a new question? I'd hazard a guess it's slightly more difficult to build, or at least a different feature to the team. - Do you know any online playground that already has this feature?