# Do I need to put onloads and main elements in code snippets?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

RELATED: [Allow us to choose a doctype for Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272915/allow-us-to-choose-a-doctype-for-stack-snippets)

---

I can put this in a code snippet:

```js
$("#box").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<div id="box">Hello, World!</div>
```

I can also do this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#box").css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <div id="box">Hello, World!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does the code snippet system automatically fill in the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, etc. and start executing JS when the page has finished loading, or are you supposed to put that manually?

---

**Follow-Up Question**

According to the answer, code snippets take care of the heavy lifting. What if you want to put stuff in the <head>? Will the wrapper elements be duplicated, or will the snippets accommodate for it?

For instance, someone who wants to show differences between character encodings has to use a <meta> tag in the <head>

Comment: Do you need it... for what? Have you inspected the result of stack snippets? I’m not very clear on what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Why not *try that out*? You get to see a preview of your post as you edit it.

Comment: From the duplicate: ***HTML** - The top-left pane. Only the body content goes here. When you run the snippet, it will be wrapped in markup including `<body>...</body>` tags.*. That post is linked from the [help center page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: A follow-up question should be made in an actual follow-up question.  Make a new question, ask your follow-up, and link the original question that it's a follow-up to.  The way that you've done this is a chameleon question, and is very much the wrong way to go about asking, either here on meta, but especially on the main SO site.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit adding a new question. Stack Overflow aims to build a collection of questions and answers for future visitors to find and get a benefit from. They need to be able to identify the question as covering the same problem they are seeing, and putting multiple questions into one post muddies the waters. Moreover, it makes it harder to determine if the answers given address just the initial question, the additional question, or both. Don't add questions to existing posts, please.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272915/4356188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `<html>`, `<head>`, etc. tags in a code snippet. It will take care of the heavy lifting for you, allowing you to concentrate on the important parts of the question.

Think as it of a built-in way to help you produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What if I need to use the head?

Comment: @sag and why you will need the head? there is no need for title, meta, etc, etc .. and if you want to inlcude external CSS or JS you can do it within the body

Comment: @TemaniAfif What if the question asks about the usage of a **meta tag?** Can the answerer make examples with snippets?

Comment: @sag and what will be the purpose of a runnable snippet if it's about meta tag? ... you don't need. The main purpose of snippet code is to create a running code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Like if someone wants to demo mobile device scaling or character encodings.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272915/4356188